# How do I extract name/value pairs from a string in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data enclosed in curly brackets in the form {year, value} in F48 in the following way:

[image]

I would like to write a formula that will subtract the value for year 1990 from the value for year 2017, then divide the difference by the value for year 1990, but I don't know how.

I thought the easiest way to do this would be to use the INDEX and MATCH functions. In the cell where we'd want the result, we'd enter the following formula:

```
=(INDEX(karnkraft,MATCH(2017,karnkraft,0),2)-INDEX(karnkraft,MATCH(1990,karnkraft,0),2))/INDEX(karnkraft,MATCH(1990,karnkraft,0),2)
```

This formula will look up the value for 2017 in the karnkraft data and subtract the value for 1990, then divide that difference by the value for 1990. Will it not?

Going one step further, how do I obtain the values in a new column in the form {year, value}, in the following way:

1. Quotient will multiply with the value from year 1990 and 2017 to obtain new min-value and max-value.
2. We'll use the max-value and min-value as a reference to get random values between these numbers for the years 1990-2017 in the form {year, value}.
3. I will rinse and repeat for different data.

Comment: Index and match are used to return cell values/locations, they are not used to parse text strings.   The first thing to do is figure out how to search a cell's text string and retrieve values.  e.g. find "1906" immediately preceded by "{" then retrieve the characters that are between the next ", " and "}"  Once you can do that you'll know how to retrieve your two numbers and can perform the math is the easy part.

Comment: adding to @BlindSpots, apply some cleanup formulas, then use `TEXTSPLIT()` then you might be able to use index/match

Answer (score 0):

Question should be revised to:
**How do I extract name/value pairs from a string in Excel?**

```
=MID(C1,
      SEARCH("{"&A1, C1)+LEN(A1)+2,
      SEARCH("}", C1, SEARCH("{"&A1, C1))-1-SEARCH("{"&A1, C1)-LEN(A1)-2)
```

#### Explanation

Lets assume you have the following data/string in a single cell 'C1'

karnkraft={{1990, 2000.642591}, {1991, 2096.356868}, {1992, 2112.277946}, {1993, 2185.016841}, {1994, 2226.050783}, {1995, 2641.599256}, {2004, 2757.124087}, {2005, 2746.479825}, {2008, 2737.860822}, {2009, 2575.664304}, {2016, 2612.83283}, {2017, 2322.592422}, {1996, 2407.002623}, {1997, 2390.480054}, {1998, 2431.571247}, {1999, 2524.546817}, {2000, 2580.976669}, {2001, 2653.821898}, {2002, 2696.204132}, {2003, 2769.046942}, {2006, 2803.605088}, {2007, 2699.245242}, {2010, 2767.507814}, {2011, 2651.771616}, {2012, 2472.44864}, {2013, 2491.705601}, {2014, 2541.027341}, {2015, 2635.561104}};

You'd like to pull a VALUE from a NAME VALUE pair, where the NAME is a year.

1. In cell 'A1' we'll place the NAME (year) to find, in this case '1991'
2. We then want to locate the position of the NAME placed in 'A1' ('1991' in this example).  In order to find the NAME '1991', we search for "{1991".  We include the "{" because VALUES are also numbers and we don't want a false positive.  No VALUES start with "{".

```
 =SEARCH("{"&A1, C1) 
 =SEARCH("{1991",C1)
 =33
```

3. To determine the left-most position of our VALUE, we use the position of our NAME from step #2 (33) and increase that number by its length (LEN) as well as any additional spaces, punctuation, etc.

```
 =33 + length of 'A1' + 2   // + 2 char for ", "
 =33 + len(A1) + 2
 =33 + 4 + 2
 =39

  
Position:  33   39
String: ...{1991, 2096.356868}... 
Count:      123456
```

4. To get the right-most position of our VALUE.  We search for the position of the "}" that immediately follows the position of our NAME from step #2 (33).

```
 =SEARCH("}", C1, 33)
 =51

  
Position:  33               51 // next "}"
String: ...{1991, 2096.356868}...
```

5. We can now determine the length (LEN) of our VALUE by subtracting the left-most position from step #3 (39) from the right-most position from step #4 (51) - 1 (because we don't want the "}" that follows our VALUE:

```
 =51-1-39   // left-most - 1 - right-most
 =11        // LEN of VALUE

  
Position:  33                           51 // next "}"
String: ...{1991, 2 0 9 6 . 3 5 6 8 6  8 }... 
                  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

6. All that remains is to plug our results into MID and extract our VALUE:

```
 =MID(text, start_num, num_chars)
 =MID(C1, 39, 11)
 =2096.356868
```

7. You could use helper cells for repetitive portions of the formula, but the full formula without any helper cells is:

```
 =MID(text,
      start_num,
      num_chars)
 =MID(C1,
      SEARCH("{"&A1, C1)+LEN(A1)+2,
      SEARCH("}", C1, SEARCH("{"&A1, C1))-1-SEARCH("{"&A1, C1)-LEN(A1)-2)
 =MID(C1,
      33+LEN("1991")+2,
      SEARCH("}", C1, SEARCH("{1991", C1))-1-SEARCH("{1991", C1)-LEN("1991")-2)
 =MID(C1,
      33+4+2,
      51-1-33-4-2)
 =MID(C1,
      39,
      51-1-33-4-2)
 =2096.35686
```

### [image]

#### Better ways to store data

Given that this is a spreadsheet, storing the data pairs in a table makes much more sense and would facilitate extraction and other calculations.

Here is an example of what I presume would be half the data from two cells, with 3 different sorts applied.  The data is accessible and you can perform a lot of calculations (including Index/Match).
[image: sample data img]

Answer (score -1):

As I understand the data, leading off with "karnkraft" then a space, the "=" and another space before the bracketed values, the following would work, if you have the new text functions:

```
=LET(YearEnd,  2017,  YearStart,  1990,
     String,  SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RIGHT(F48,LEN(F48)-14),LEN(RIGHT(F48,LEN(F48)-14))-2),"}, {","ϣ"),
     Table,  VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(String,", ","ϣ",TRUE,1)),
     End,  VLOOKUP(YearEnd,Table,2,FALSE),  Start,  VLOOKUP(YearStart,Table,2,FALSE),

     End - Start
     )
```

One might wonder why `VLOOKUP` is used instead of the (usually) nicer `XLOOKUP` (or the function pair that replaced and which has the same issue it does here, `INDEX/MATCH`). The reason is that the `Table` created virtually inside the formula is a single item and so referencing it for `XLOOKUP`'s lookup array is easy, but referencing it for its return array is... not. `VLOOKUP` lets you regard the entire entity because you return a column in it, not a referenced column.

The key, of course, is `TEXTSPLIT` which makes having it nice. It needs preparation though, so the string is formed by removing the leading characters up to and including the "{{" with `RIGHT`. (And the "14" that is stripped off would need changed if, for instance, it is not `karnkraft = {{` but rather, say, `karnkraft={{`.) Then the ending "}}" is stripped off with the `LEFT`.

Finally, since the delimiters one needs to use for splitting it into rows of two columns both have the `,`  (comma-space) in them (exactly that for one, and that wrapped by "}{" for the other), one of them needs replaced with some unique and not containing the `,` . Hence the `SUBSTITUTE`.

It's all in a `LET` for easier readability. If one does not have that either, it just needs the variables' formulas substituted in where they occur. It will look complicated and evil, but it would be the same thing. *(I'd usually say "mostly" as `LET` allows a calculation to be done once, then the result used however many times in the formula and that can lead to a faster formula which, in a large usage, can make the spreadsheet much more responsive. But in this case, nothing really gets used more than once so its main advantage is the readability.)*

If I misunderstood the data source, it won't work. But very likely you could modify it to a small extent and make it work on the actual data set.